# How to solve data resolution problem when using Prometheus irate() function in the Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-variable

My exporter scrapes metrics every 5 seconds. I set the range-vector of the query to 10 seconds, which is 2x of scrape interval, in order to catch 'spikes and dips'.

The problem is Grafana automatically controls the resolution(step) of the graph, and I'm losing some data points when I set a long time range.

Trivial solution is using `$__interval` or `$__rate_interval` variable instead of constant range vector.

But if I use variable for range-vector, I will lose many data points when I monitor a long time range graph. Because `irate()` considers only the last two samples.

Is it okay to use `irate()` in Grafana? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, as the scope of the data grows, you have to give up on looking at all the raw data, because of performance.

What I can do is to reduce the resolution of the data in some way. In Prometheus, there are [`<aggregation>_over_time` functions](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time): `avg_over_time`, `max_over_time`, etc.

If you are curious about the average trend of your raw data, you can use `avg_over_time`. On the other hand, if you want to capture the spikes that occurred in the raw data, you can apply `max_over_time`. If you are curious about the dips, you can apply `min_over_time`. I applied `max_over_time` to capture the spike at the time.

Naturally, the lookup will be slower because of the extra maths that are being added to the raw data. I was willing to take the performance hit for accurate monitoring.

Comment: "you have to give up on looking at all the raw data, because of performance" and also graph can't always visualize every data point: there is only so much pixels for this.